# Assembly has a higher version than referenced. EPI5 to EPI6

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly, episerver

After a succesfull uppgrade from EPi5 to EPi6 i get this error

```
    Error   101 Assembly 'EPiServer.Web.WebControls, Version=6.0.530.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7' uses 'EPiServer, Version=6.0.530.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'EPiServer, 
Version=5.2.375.236, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7'  
c:\EPiServer\Sites\UppgraderaSiteName\SiteName.Web\bin\EPiServer.Web.WebControls.dll    
SiteName.Web
```

The DLL is configured in web.config as 6.0.530.0
   In the reference it says 6.0.530.0
   The DLL file also says 6.0.530.0

There is something im not getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting the references of  "EPiServer.Web.WebControls.dll" from the Solution Explorer & then add references of correct version.

Also, you can open the Project Files (".csproj" or ".vbproj") in notepad & check the `<Reference/>` Elements, to verify that correct version is being used:

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference/>
    ...
    <Reference/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I get this in the .CsProj
"  <Reference Include="EPiServer.Web.WebControls, Version=6.1.379.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">"

So it seems to reference the correct version, no? 

I have also deleted and re-referenced in the solution explorer.

Comment: For others with the same problem: The EpiServer.DLL reference pointed to v5 instead of v6.